# gson JsonSyntaxException to Java Date from .net DateTime

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How can I convert C#'s DateTime format from gson to Java Date?
In gson which setDateFormat is correct?
C#

`DateTime time = DateTime.Now;`

JSON

```
{
  "date_time": "2015-04-24T09:22:08.6964069+08:00"
}
```

Android

```
private Date date_time;

Gson gson=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();
gson.fromJson(resultString, objectClass);

E/AndroidRuntime(24671): Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2015-04-24T16:20:08.3672729+08:00
E/AndroidRuntime(24671): Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-04-24T16:20:08.3672729+08:00"
E/AndroidRuntime(24671): at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(24671): at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:79)
```

Comment: I could imagine that your pattern doesnt work. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sZ` or with Java 7 `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sX` should do it?

Comment: I tried but it is not work.
`Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2015-04-27T09:23:34.982338+08:00
            at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)`

`Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-04-27T09:23:34.982338+08:00" (at offset 19)
            at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'
            at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validateFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:268)`

Comment: Well my fault, you ofc have to provide the digit amount and use the correct time zone. (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't work with the `X` pattern symbol wich is typically used for the `ISO 8601 time zone` you cannot take care of this date format, because of the colon in the time zone. If you can make use of it, the pattern would look like this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSXXX
```

A workaround would be to handle it as a `String`, remove the colon from it (e.g. `replaceAll(String)` and afterwards format it with the `RFC 822 time zone` (pattern symbol `Z`):

```
String time = inputTime.replaceAll("([\\+\\-]\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)","$1$2"));
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZ");
Date myDate = format.parse(time);
```

Note: Because of the combination of milliseconds and time zone, you have to hardset the digitamount.

The [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)  provides the underlying conventions, as stated in the [GsonDoc](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat(java.lang.String)).

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZ`  That is correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For `DateTime.UtcNow` the pattern will be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"`
, the full code will be

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").create();
```